# Objective C typed Class pointer

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

So, we do have this nice "Class" type in Objective C, which allows us to reference classes, but is it possible to add a type like that:

```
Class<NSObject> test1 = [NSObject class];
test1 = [NSString class]; // OK, since NSString is a child of NSObject
Class<NSString> test2 = [NSMutableString class]; // also OK
test2 = [NSObject class]; // Badabumm, this should make the compiler complain
```

I do know that Class does not accept generics, but is this behaviour possible, I considered the following options:

1. Normally, an NSObject instance would have the type NSObject*, if we want to reference the class of NSObject, can we use the name of the metaclass like that: NSObject_metaclass*?
2. Re-Implement "Class" with generics, but from my understanding this would only allow runtime checking
3. Some hacky way?
4. Runtime check it, but I am not very fond of this idea, I want the compiler to notify me about type missmatches.

Thank you in advance & sry for my english,
thejack

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C doesn't really have any way to do this. You may want to look into Swift, which is much stricter about compile-time type safety than Objective-C, and is largely compatible with existing Objective-C code on Apple platforms.